# Adding Menu Subitems By Getting File Names from Directory

Tags: c#, winforms

Code:

```
private void loadViewTemplates(string path)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"))
    {
        ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        viewTemplatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
    }
}
```

I have three files in the source directory, they seem to appear as the menu subitem, but the file names did not appear.

[image: Menu subitem]

Is there a way I can make the file names' appear instead of invisible? Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the

```
subItem.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.text.aspx)

```
ToolStripItem.Text - Gets or sets the text that is to be displayed on the item.
```

So the code will be

```
private void loadViewTemplates(string path)  
{  
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"))  
    {  
        ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();  
        subItem.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        viewTemplatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding. :) but this will return the whole path "..\..\Folder\filename.txt" as the item unless i replace `file;` with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);`. I have found my solution. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Well I don't know if you want all the file or not. Of course the Path class contains all the method you need to work on filenames.

Comment: Hi Steve, if you don't mind, can you kindly explain which way is better? the one in your answer or my code `viewTemplatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));`? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, passing directly a string to the ToolStripItemCollection means that the framework will build for you a ToolStripItem and add it to the collection. However, I find the solution that creates a ToolStripItem, although it is probably slower, more readable.

Comment: Thank you :)) (if you saw my deleted reply, please ignore, I have got it fixed) :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution myself as below:

```
private void loadViewTemplates(string path)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"))
    {
        viewTemplatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}
```

Thank you.